# how open specific account record by customerid / telephone no in Dynamic CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

i need to open a specific account based on url. i have a requirement that open a account against telephone no/customer id using query string. i try these urls

http://ef.crm/EFCRMDB/main.aspx?etn=account&pagetype=entityrecord (this open a create new account form)

http://ef.crm/EFCRMDB/main.aspx?etn=account&extraqs=etc%3d1%26expert_test%3dabcdef&pagetype=entityrecord       (pass query string value and i successfully get this value on form)

In database AccountBase table i find unique id for record  that is 'AccountId'.

this works fine for me

http://ef.crm/EFCRMDB/main.aspx?etn=account&pagetype=entityrecord&id=A3D57E8C-87F6-E111-8BF8-000C29E2596B

now problem is that how i get 'AccountId' against telephone no or customer id received form url? can i open account by dialog or workflow if yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can also make a HTML+JS Web Resource and upload it to the Dynamic CRM. You then can access the web resource through URL.

The web you upload must do things as follows:

1. Fetch the telephone no from the query string
2. Do Fetch XML call from JavaScript. Pass the telephone no as a parameter and than get the Id of the account.
3. Open the account window you want by passing the account Id in the query string.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure there is anything out of the box that will give you the Id. But you could try:

- Dialogs and Workflows now have an option for getting the url of a record.

[image]

- You could create a custom workflow activity (for use in dialogs and workflows) to get the Id
- If your in JavaScript you can do: [Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334720.aspx#BKMK_getId)